# Why can't my spotlight open any application?

Tags: applications, spotlight

I can search and find anything on Spotlight, so I think my index works. However, when I try to open an application, even terminal, I just get a spinning beach ball until Spotlight disappears. Why am I having this problem?

Comment: There are probably more details required to get to the bottom of this. Does the problem occur directly after a reboot as well? Did you try to rebuild your Spotlight index? Is there anything of interest in /var/log/system.log? If you change to another user (create one if necessary), does the same problem occur there?

Comment: Actually my log says this `Dec 16 11:48:05 JonatharantsMBP coreduetd[65]: CoreData: error: (11) Fatal error.  The database at /var/db/CoreDuet/coreduetd.db is corrupted.  SQLite error code:11, 'database disk image is malformed'
Dec 16 11:48:05 JonatharantsMBP coreduetd[65]: Core Data: error: -executeRequest: encountered exception = Fatal error.  The database at /var/db/CoreDuet/coreduetd.db is corrupted.  SQLite error code:11, 'database disk image is malformed' with userInfo = {
     NSFilePath = "/var/db/CoreDuet/coreduetd.db";
     NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 11;
 }`

Comment: An issue not completely unknown to the mighty Google, me thinks :-) I didn't even know this database existed till 5 minutes ago, so honestly I don't know how to fix this. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6617864?start=0&tstart=0 indicates that there might also be a coreduetd log file (check with Console.app).